# Javascript Regex: How to put a function argument inside a regular expression?

Tags: javascript, regex

I have the following javascript function with one argument

```
<script type="text/javascript">
function highlight(text) {
  var inputText = document.getElementById("inputText");
  var innerHTML = inputText.innerHTML;
  var index = innerHTML.indexOf(text);
  if (index >= 0) {
    innerHTML = innerHTML.replace(/YYYYYYYYY/gi, '<span class="highlight">' + text + '</span>');
   inputText.innerHTML = innerHTML;
  }
}
</script>
```

How can i put function argument `text` inside this regex rather than `YYYYYYYYY`

```
innerHTML = innerHTML.replace(/YYYYYYYYY/gi, '<span class="highlight">' + text + '</span>');
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use the regex constructor:

```
re = new RegExp (text, "gi")
```

Comment: Thank you and it works perfect `var re = new RegExp (text, "gi");` and then 
`innerHTML = innerHTML.replace(re, '<span class="highlight">$&</span>');`